# Can someone help me to identify what kind of pear is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, food, trees, fruit

I went to my local groceries supermarket (in Lima, Peru) and found this cheerful looking pear named locally as "pera canela". But I found it weird as the only variety which I'm aware of is [Packham's pears](http://www.thefoodcoach.com.au/food/?Action=View&FoodID=141). I tried to do some research on different cultivars and species known of pears. So far the only ones which I found were in this [wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pear_cultivars) but it didn't help me much.

Below is a set of pictures I took of the pear referred to as "pera canela"

[image: Picture of packed Pera canela]

*Figure 1. Picture of packed Pera canela, the printed label shows its local name.*

[image: Picture of sample of Pera canela on groceries stand]

*Figure 2. Picture of Pera canela's as they are on a basket in groceries stand. Seen in the background.*

[image: Picture of Pera canela closer]

*Figure 3. Picture of Pera canela seen closer for identification.*

I've tasted it and it is a little bit more sweeter than the Packham's variety, on the juicier factor I would say that it is pretty much the same as Packham's

So far by comparing it with different entries on Wikipedia. I'm not very sure if it's a local name given to either [Abate fetel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abate_Fetel) or perhaps to [Bosc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosc_pear)
 varieties, or could it be a [D'Anjou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Anjou)?

Since I'm not good at identifying plants, can somebody help me identify which kind of pear it is? It would also greatly help me if the answer could include its scientific name so I could do more research into it.

Answer (score 9):

[Plu Code](https://www.ifpsglobal.com/Identification/PLU-Codes) 4413 is a [**bosc**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosc_pear) pear (a cultivar of [*Pyrus communis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_communis)).

[image]

From the PLU search tool available via the [International Federation for Produce Standards](https://www.ifpsglobal.com/Identification/PLU-Codes/PLU-codes-Search)

[image]

FYI: take a close look at the pear you're holding in your picture:

[image]

Pera canela, meaning "cinnamon pear" in English, is in reference to its color. From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosc_pear):

> Famous for its warm cinnamon color

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89691/discussion-on-answer-by-theforestecologist-can-someone-help-me-to-identify-what).